# Problems with def

Tags: math-mode, macros

I have created the following macros in LaTeX:

```
\def\twomate(#1,#2,#3,#4){\begin{pmatrix}#1&#2\\#3&#4\end{pmatrix}}
\def\pwr(#1){^{#1}}
\def\twoclmn(#1,#2){\begin{pmatrix}#1\\#2\end{pmatrix}}
```

Where `\twomate` is a 2x2 matrix, `\twoclmn` creates a 2x1 column vector, and `\pwr` is a command to raise the argument to the power.
However, if I try to do the following:

```
$$\twomate(3e\pwr(-3t),e\pwr(2t),-e\pwr(-3t),-2e\pwr(2t) )$$
```

I get an error. However, if I replace the last entry with something that is not a `def` command:

```
$$\twomate(3e\pwr(-3t),e\pwr(2t),-e\pwr(-3t),5 )$$
```

The document complies successfully. In addition, the following does not compile successfully:

```
$$\twoclmn(\frac{6}{25}e\pwr(2t)-\frac15te\pwr(2t),-\frac{2}{25}e\pwr(2t) + \frac25 t e\pwr(2t))$$
```

But the following does:

```
$$\twoclmn(\frac{6}{25}e^{2t}-\frac15te^{2t},-\frac{2}{25}e^{2t} + \frac25 t e^{2t})$$
```

So the problem seems to be the nested `\def` commands. How may I nest `\def` commands, without the compiler complaining?

Comment: Since you're using LaTeX, please consider using `\[ ... \]` instead of `$$ ... $$`, as the latter causes some inconsistencies.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `xparse` for this job, because the `r` argument type takes care of nesting.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\twomate}{>{\SplitArgument{3}{,}}r()}{%
  \maketwomate#1%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\maketwomate}{mmmm}{%
  \begin{pmatrix}#1&#2\\#3&#4\end{pmatrix}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\pwr}{r()}{^{#1}}

\begin{document}

\[
\twomate(3e\pwr(-3t),e\pwr(2t),-e\pwr(-3t),-2e\pwr(2t) )
\]

\end{document}
```

However, using `()` as delimiters doesn't seem a good idea. The following is as clear and behaves better with syntax coloring of front ends.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\twomate}{>{\SplitArgument{3}{,}}m}{%
  \maketwomate#1%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\maketwomate}{mmmm}{%
  \begin{pmatrix}#1&#2\\#3&#4\end{pmatrix}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\pwr}{m}{^{#1}}

\begin{document}

\[
\twomate{3e\pwr{-3t},e\pwr{2t},-e\pwr{-3t},-2e\pwr{2t}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: can one nest like this `\foo(a,\bar(b,c,d),\baz(e,f),g)` ?

Comment: @jfbu Yes, but why? There's no advantage whatsoever over braces.

Comment: actually I now tried and it does not seem to work with the code you posted (`LaTeX error: "xparse/split-excess-tokens"`). So I guess you meant "yes it can be done", not "yes, it does it". Again I agree that TeX has its own syntax and trying to use another one (with all induced complications) is not the way to go for user macros.

Comment: @jfbu Without seeing how you define `\foo`, `\bar` and `\baz` it's just guesswork.

Comment: `\twomate(\twomate(1,2,3,4),5,6,7)`,  with `\NewDocumentCommand{\maketwomate}{mmmm}{(#1+#2+#3+#4)}` in place of the definition in your code

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for :) I applied the same format to the `\twoclmn` command and it worked like a charm. I appreciate it.

Comment: @jfbu Yes, I can confirm the issue. I guess that the two checks, the one for `()` and the one for commas, get confused by the double interaction. Too bad, but I don't think that investigating this further is worth the trouble. Using braces will avoid all problems and is not at all more difficult than using `()`.

Comment: (I think an explanatory edit should tell users that the "nesting" simply does not work when comma separated arguments are in use as in the OP query)

Answer (score 10):

Your `\def` contains a very specific sequence defined as the parameter text:

```
%           1   2   3   4   5
\def\twomate(<1>,<2>,<3>,<4>){ ... }
%           ^   ^   ^   ^   ^
%           │   │   │   │   │
%           │   └ comma ┘   │
%           └─── bracket ───┘
```

This parameter text is matched exactly in order (almost like a first-come-first-served style) to extract the four arguments `<1>`, `<2>`, `<3>` and `<4>`. Here's how the elements are grabbed for `\twomate` with the above notation:

```
%       1           2         3           4          5
\twomate(3e\pwr(-3t),e\pwr(2t),-e\pwr(-3t),-2e\pwr(2t))
%       ^           ^         ^           ^          ^
%       │           │         │           │          │
%       │           └────── comma ────────┘          │
%       └───────────────── bracket ──────────────────┘
```

It should be clear that the last bracket `)` isn't properly captured for `\pwr`. The way around it is to hide `\pwr(.)` from `\twomate`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\def\twomate(#1,#2,#3,#4){\begin{pmatrix}#1&#2\\#3&#4\end{pmatrix}}
\def\pwr(#1){^{#1}}

\begin{document}

\[
  \twomate(3e\pwr(-3t),e\pwr(2t),-e\pwr(-3t),{-2e\pwr(2t)})
\]

\end{document}
```

This solves the problem only temporarily. If you nest elements, you'll run into similar problems because of the parameter text pattern matching. In general, it is safer to group arguments using `{`...`}`.

Answer (score 6):

TeX's delimited parameters parsing doesn't take nesting into account properly. So if you call `\twomate(3e\pwr(-3t), ...)`, the final `)` for `\twomate` isn't found at the end of that line but at the end of `\pwr(-3t)`. The improperly formed call of `\pwr` then causes trouble.

To hide nested calls of your commands, put them into `{ ... }` groups (though this probably defeats the purpose):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\def\twomate(#1,#2,#3,#4){\begin{pmatrix}#1&#2\\#3&#4\end{pmatrix}}
\def\pwr(#1){^{#1}}
\def\twoclmn(#1,#2){\begin{pmatrix}#1\\#2\end{pmatrix}}

\begin{document}
\[ \twomate({3e\pwr(-3t)},{e\pwr(2t)},{-e\pwr(-3t)},{-2e\pwr(2t)}) \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, don't use `$$ ... $$` for display math environments but LaTeX's or `amsmath`'s variants like `\[ ... \]`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to define macros expecting comma separated arguments enclosed in parentheses. The code converts any standard LaTeX command (macro with non-delimited parameters) into one expecting `(..., ..., ...)` input syntax. When used, the number of arguments must be the one expected by the macro, there is no error-checking.

Nesting works, as we will test with this kind of input:

```
\foo(\Bar(3,5,7),\Bar(9,\foo(a,\Bar(W,X,Y),c,d),13),\Bar(15,17,19),\Bar(21,23,25))
```

Attention that there is no special handling of spaces in the input, and also some brace-stripping may occur in certain circumstances.

As this all works purely by expansion, expandable commands remain expandable commands.

<sub>**Important**: for a fuller implementation of the analogy with "functional notation", the macro `\foo(\a, \b, \c)` should *first* expand completely the `\a`, `\b`, `\c` before doing whatever it wants to do (if only for reasons of efficiency). But this would limit from the start such constructs to the realm of expandable macros. And furthermore, only the new `\expanded` primitive allows (easy) such complete expansion. Else, one can make do restricting to only "first-fully" expandable macros using some `` \romannumeral-`Q `` governed expansion (with a problem if macro expands to something starting with a space token.) Anyway, here I did not add the automatic expansion of `\a, \b, \c`, before applying the `\foo` macro, I stayed more on the side of usual macro expansion in TeX for things such as `\foo{\a}{\b}{\c}`.</sub>

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% copy over some utility code from package xintexpr
\catcode`_ 11

\makeatletter
\let\xint_c_mone\m@ne
\let\xint_c_\z@
\let\xint_c_i\@ne
\long\def\xint_bye #1\xint_bye {}%
\makeatother
% THE \XINT_isbalanced_... MACROS COPIED OVER FROM XINTEXPR CODE MADE
% HERE ALL \long
% %    \end{macrocode}
% \subsubsection{\csh{XINT_isbalanced_a} for \cshnolabel{XINT_expr_onliteral_seq_a}}
% \lverb|Expands to \xint_c_mone in case a closing ) had no opening ( matching
% it, to \@ne if opening ( had no closing ) matching it, to \z@ if expression
% was balanced.|
%    \begin{macrocode}
% use as \XINT_isbalanced_a \relax #1(\xint_bye)\xint_bye
\long\def\XINT_isbalanced_a #1({\XINT_isbalanced_b #1)\xint_bye }%
\long\def\XINT_isbalanced_b #1)#2%
   {\xint_bye #2\XINT_isbalanced_c\xint_bye\XINT_isbalanced_error }%
%    \end{macrocode}
% \lverb|if #2 is not \xint_bye, a ) was found, but there was no (. Hence error -> -1|
%    \begin{macrocode}
\long\def\XINT_isbalanced_error #1)\xint_bye {\xint_c_mone}%
%    \end{macrocode}
% \lverb|#2 was \xint_bye, was there a ) in original #1?|
%    \begin{macrocode}
\long\def\XINT_isbalanced_c\xint_bye\XINT_isbalanced_error #1%
    {\xint_bye #1\XINT_isbalanced_yes\xint_bye\XINT_isbalanced_d #1}%
%    \end{macrocode}
% \lverb|#1 is \xint_bye, there was never ( nor ) in original #1, hence OK.|
%    \begin{macrocode}
\long\def\XINT_isbalanced_yes\xint_bye\XINT_isbalanced_d\xint_bye )\xint_bye {\xint_c_ }%
%    \end{macrocode}
% \lverb|#1 is not \xint_bye, there was indeed a ( in original #1. We check if
% we see a ). If we do, we then loop until no ( nor ) is to be found.|
%    \begin{macrocode}
\long\def\XINT_isbalanced_d #1)#2%
   {\xint_bye #2\XINT_isbalanced_no\xint_bye\XINT_isbalanced_a #1#2}%
%    \end{macrocode}
% \lverb|#2 was \xint_bye, we did not find a closing ) in original #1. Error.|
%    \begin{macrocode}
\long\def\XINT_isbalanced_no\xint_bye #1\xint_bye\xint_bye {\xint_c_i }%

% NEW EXPANDABLE UTILITY

\long\def\applyfunction #1#2)%
{%
    \ifcase\XINT_isbalanced_a \relax #1#2)(\xint_bye)\xint_bye
           \expandafter\applyfunction_b
        \or\expandafter\applyfunction_again
      \else\expandafter\we_are_doomed
    \fi {#1#2}%
}%
\long\def\applyfunction_again #1{\applyfunction {#1)}}%
\long\def\my_bbye #1\my_bbye {}%
\long\def\applyfunction_b #1{\applyfunction_c #1,\my_bbye,}%
\long\def\applyfunction_c #1({\applyfunction_d #1{}{}}%
% we will take care of brace removal another day
\long\def\applyfunction_d #1#2#3#4,%
{%
    \ifcase\XINT_isbalanced_a \relax #3#4(\xint_bye)\xint_bye
           \expandafter\applyfunction_e
        \or\expandafter\applyfunction_d_again
      \else\expandafter\we_are_doomed
    \fi #1{#2}{#3}{#4}%
}%
\long\def\applyfunction_d_again #1#2#3#4%
{%
    \applyfunction_d #1{#2}{#3#4,}%
}%
\long\def\applyfunction_e #1#2#3#4%
{%
    \my_bbye#4\applyfunction_finish\my_bbye
    \applyfunction_g #1{#2}{#3#4}%
}%
\long\def\applyfunction_g #1#2#3{\applyfunction_d #1{#2{#3}}{}}%
\long\def\applyfunction_finish\my_bbye\applyfunction_g #1#2#3{#1#2}%

\catcode`_ 8

%% USAGE
% to define a "function" to be used as \foo(a,b,c,...),
% we need a \foomacro which uses standard non-delimited parameters,
% thus e.g. defined via \newcommand, and then one only needs
% \newcommand\foo{\applyfunction\foomacro}
% to get a \foo to be used with parentheses.

\newcommand\twomate{\applyfunction\twomatemacro}
\newcommand\pwr{\applyfunction\pwrmacro}
\newcommand\twoclmn{\applyfunction\twoclmnmacro}

% define here the **non-delimited** auxiliary macros
\newcommand\twomatemacro[4]{\begin{pmatrix}#1&#2\\#3&#4\end{pmatrix}}
\newcommand\pwrmacro[1]{^{#1}}
\newcommand\twoclmnmacro[2]{\begin{pmatrix}#1\\#2\end{pmatrix}}

%% TESTING NESTING
\newcommand\foo{\applyfunction\foomacro}
\newcommand\foomacro[4]{\left[#1+#2+#3+#4\right]}
\let\Bar\relax
\newcommand\Bar{\applyfunction\Barmacro}
\newcommand\Barmacro[3]{\left(#1*#2*#3\right)}

\delimiterfactor1001

\begin{document}

\[
  \twomate(3e\pwr(-3t),e\pwr(2t),-e\pwr(-3t),-2e\pwr(2t))
\]
\[
  \twoclmn(\frac{6}{25}e\pwr(2t)-\frac15te\pwr(2t),-\frac{2}{25}e\pwr(2t)
  + \frac25 t e\pwr(2t))
\]
\[\foo(\Bar(3,5,7),\Bar(9,\foo(a,\Bar(W,X,Y),c,d),13),\Bar(15,17,19),\Bar(21,23,25))\]
\end{document}
```

[image]